# Is there a way I can call powershell 2.0 from MVC 4 app

Tags: powershell

I guess a better question is there a way I can call a command line from a web app?

I saw the following link in an answer to a similar question [Link to Blog about calling powershell](http://devinfra-us.blogspot.com/2011/02/using-powershell-20-from-aspnet-part-1.html)

but apparently I do not have the right version in my environment (that includes our test and production environment) and it is going to be quite a lift to get management to budge on getting the software needed.  If I could just make a call to the command line I could make the call as needed.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use System.Management.Automation, you can always use the good old Process, which will spawn a console (which can be made invisible), however if you plan on using it a lot, it might not be the most efficient approach.

```
using System.Diagnostics;

// ...

var process = Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo("powershell.exe") {
    Arguments = @"C:\MyScript.ps1",
    WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
});
```

If you need to wait for the process to finish, you simply have to do

```
process.WaitForExit()
```

Just make sure your process *does* exit!